# Basic R output: Show the label and its unclass value & Do not alphabetize/numerically order results

Tags: r

Still learning much about R, having work mostly in Stata & SPSS.

2 part, interconnected questions:

1) How can I get R to NOT produce output in alphabetical order or number order using the first digit(s) of numeric values?

Let's say I have a vector of factor data representing numerical info *(counts are not important for this example)*:

```
  widgets = c("One widget", "Two widgets", "Three widgets", "Four widgets", "Five widgets", "Six widgets", "Seven widgets", "Eight widgets", "Nine widgets", "Ten to Fifteen widgets", "Sixteen or more widgets")
```

I run a basic table and I get:

```
    table(widgets)
    widgets
    Eight widgets   Five widgets   Four widgets   Nine widgets   One widget Zero widgets
                1              1             1             1             1   1
```

but I want R to give me:

```
            table(widgets)
    widgets
    Zero widgets   One widget   Four widgets   Five widgets   Eight widgets Nine widgets
               1            1              1             1              1   1
```

I like to use cbind to make things easier to read, but it suffers the same output ordering:

```
  cbind(table(widgets))
                    [,1]
  Eight widgets        1
  Five widgets         1
  Four widgets         1
  Nine widgets         1
  One widget           1
  Zero widgets         1
```

2) The data from above has an underlying number value that I can see using the unclass(widgets) function.  So how can I get the unclass values to display alongside my string labels in my tables?

My unclass:

```
    cbind(unclass(widgets))
         [,1]           
    [1,] "Zero widgets" 
    [2,] "One widget"   
    [3,] "Four widgets" 
    [4,] "Five widgets" 
    [5,] "Eight widgets"
    [6,] "Nine widgets"
```

What I want or similar to this:

```
    cbind(unclass(widgets))
    unclass  label     Freq           
    1   Zero widgets      1
    2   One widget        1
    3   Four widgets      1
    4   Five widgets      1
    5   Eight widgets     1
    6   Nine widgets      1
```

Getting that last table would REALLY help me with recoding and other work. 
Thanks!

Comment: Probably easiest to convert your initial vector to a factor and provide your desired order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Overview

Encode `widget` as a [`factor`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/factor.html) to get your desired results.

```
# make widgets
# a factor class
widgets <- 
    factor(
        x = c("One widget"
              , "Two widgets"
              , "Three widgets"
              , "Four widgets"
              , "Five widgets"
              , "Six widgets"
              , "Seven widgets"
              , "Eight widgets"
              , "Nine widgets"
              , "Ten to Fifteen widgets"
              , "Sixteen or more widgets"
            )
        , levels = c("One widget"
                     , "Two widgets"
                     , "Three widgets"
                     , "Four widgets"
                     , "Five widgets"
                     , "Six widgets"
                     , "Seven widgets"
                     , "Eight widgets"
                     , "Nine widgets"
                     , "Ten to Fifteen widgets"
                     , "Sixteen or more widgets"
        )
    )

# view table output
table( widgets )
# widgets
# One widget             Two widgets 
#          1                       1 
# Three widgets            Four widgets 
#             1                       1 
# Five widgets             Six widgets 
#            1                       1 
# Seven widgets           Eight widgets 
#             1                       1 
# Nine widgets  Ten to Fifteen widgets 
#            1                       1 
# Sixteen or more widgets 
#                       1 

# transform widgets
# count into data frame
widgets.count <-
    data.frame(
        table( widgets )
    )
# view data frame
widgets.count
#                    widgets Freq
# 1               One widget    1
# 2              Two widgets    1
# 3            Three widgets    1
# 4             Four widgets    1
# 5             Five widgets    1
# 6              Six widgets    1
# 7            Seven widgets    1
# 8            Eight widgets    1
# 9             Nine widgets    1
# 10  Ten to Fifteen widgets    1
# 11 Sixteen or more widgets    1

# end of script #
```

Comment: Thanks aspiringurbandatascientist!  I appreciate it.  Using the data.frame was a clever way to display the count.

Comment: @ShawnJanzen no problem, glad to help! Combining `data.frame` with `table` is a handy combination for producing counts of categorical variables.

Comment: agreed, that is handy.  I showed an (equally stumped) colleague your approach and she pointed out that your method works great if the level is equal count number.  There are instances, especially in survey data, where some variable categories might intentionally skip many level numbers (e.g. to separate "don't know", "didn't answer", and "not applicable").  Your count method would not match instances where the levels are broken discrete counts.

Comment: @ShawnJanzen I think that would be a great question to ask on SO. I don't work with survey data that much but would be interested to see a question that replicates the situation your colleague mentioned to you. I know there would be someone on here would try to solve it.